# Need MPPI Tuning help : robot turns while trying to follow straight line global path

Tags: nav2

My setup is:

- MPPI code ported to ROS Noetic and have a custom differential drive robot.
- MPPI is running at 50 hz.

I have a global plan from move_base's GlobalPlanenr (Dijkshtra's algorithm).
I started with using only one critic that is path align. I have followed the tuning guide from ReadMe.md of nav2.
My parameters are:

```
local_planner:
  time_steps: 56
  model_dt: 0.02
  batch_size: 1000
  vx_std: 0.2
  vy_std: 0.2
  wz_std: 0.4
  vx_max: 2.0
  vx_min: -2.0
  vy_max: 0.0
  wz_max: 0.8
  iteration_count: 1
  prune_distance: 100
  transform_tolerance: 0.1
  temperature: 0.3
  gamma: 0.015
  motion_model: "DiffDrive"
  visualize: false
  reset_period: 1.0 # (only in Humble)
  regenerate_noises: false
  TrajectoryVisualizer:
    trajectory_step: 5
    time_step: 3
  AckermannConstraints:
    min_turning_r: 0.0
  # critics: ["ConstraintCritic", "ObstaclesCritic", "GoalCritic", "GoalAngleCritic", "PathAlignCritic", "PathFollowCritic", "PathAngleCritic", "PreferForwardCritic"]
  critics: ["PathAlignCritic"]
  ConstraintCritic:
    enabled: true
    cost_power: 1
    cost_weight: 4.0
  GoalCritic:
    enabled: true
    cost_power: 1
    cost_weight: 5.0
    threshold_to_consider: 1.4
  GoalAngleCritic:
    enabled: true
    cost_power: 1
    cost_weight: 3.0
    threshold_to_consider: 0.5
  PreferForwardCritic:
    enabled: true
    cost_power: 1
    cost_weight: 5.0
    threshold_to_consider: 0.5
  ObstaclesCritic:
    enabled: true
    cost_power: 1
    repulsion_weight: 1.5
    critical_weight: 20.0
    consider_footprint: false
    collision_cost: 10000.0
    collision_margin_distance: 0.1
    near_goal_distance: 0.5
    inflation_radius: 0.55 # (only in Humble)
    cost_scaling_factor: 10.0 # (only in Humble)
  PathAlignCritic:
    enabled: true
    cost_power: 1
    cost_weight: 10.0
    max_path_occupancy_ratio: 0.05
    trajectory_point_step: 10
    threshold_to_consider: 0.5
    offset_from_furthest: 140
    use_path_orientations: false
  PathFollowCritic:
    enabled: true
    cost_power: 1
    cost_weight: 5.0
    offset_from_furthest: 140
    threshold_to_consider: 1.4
  PathAngleCritic:
    enabled: true
    cost_power: 1
    cost_weight: 2.0
    offset_from_furthest: 55
    threshold_to_consider: 0.5
    max_angle_to_furthest: 1.0
    mode: 0
  # TwirlingCritic:
  #   enabled: true
  #   twirling_cost_power: 1
  #   twirling_cost_weight: 10.0
```

The green straight line is the global path and the markers are the generated trajectories and optimal trajectory.
[image]

I can also share a small video for the behavior. Please let me know what would help. Thanks

Comment: You'll need to isolate variables here a bit. What happens if you enable one critic at a time, or all but one at a time? This may allow you to identify if a critic is being over-critical, and if so, reduce its impact until it's behaving appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to run the controller with just that single critic. Nothing is driving the robot forward (PathFollow), among other things. You need to look critically (he he he...) at the critics to find the minimum viable cross section to do what you want to to. There is no objective functions "built-in", you have to specify each to get each element of the total behavior.

While I understand why what you see happening is happening, its frankly not worth explaining because its conceptually totally irrelevant to what you're trying to do or what is expected of a functioning system. In effect, no critics are currently being evaluated. You won't see this behavior once you add the reasonable cross section of plugins to create the minimum demo you are potentially after. I'll say trying to go 1-by-1 is of dubious value.

See my tuning guide: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/tree/main/nav2_mppi_controller#notes-to-users

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have also tried using all the critics and I get exactly same behavior.

Comment: costs while using all the critic
critic name : ConstraintCritic
min cost : 0
max cost :0
critic name : ObstaclesCritic
min cost : 0
max cost :0
critic name : GoalCritic
min cost : 0
max cost :0
critic name : GoalAngleCritic
min cost : 0
max cost :0
return 2: 2
critic name : PathAlignCritic
min cost : 0
max cost :0
critic name : PathFollowCritic
min cost : 0.356347
max cost :1.20029
critic name : PathAngleCritic
min cost : 0.356347
max cost :1.20029
critic name : PreferForwardCritic min cost : 0.499139
max cost :1.71577

Comment: I have no idea what these min/max cost parameters are. Where did you get those from? That's not a valid configuration.

Comment: I had added logs in the evalTrajectoriesScore to see what each critic was doing. 
void CriticManager::evalTrajectoriesScores(
  CriticData & data) const
{
  for (size_t q = 0; q < critics_.size(); q++) {
    if (data.fail_flag) {
      break;
    }
    critics_[q]->score(data);
    std::cout << "critic name : " << critic_names_[q] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "min cost : " << *std::min_element(data.costs.begin(), data.costs.end()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "max cost :" << *std::max_element(data.costs.begin(), data.costs.end()) << std::endl;
  }
}